# Sly fill container with slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using [Sly slider plugin](http://darsa.in/sly/) in my project and I am new to it.

The problem I am facing right now is that when I apply `width: 100%` to the container, the other slides show on the side, thats because they have static width. [Problem demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/9dJfQ/30/)

I tried setting the slide's width to 100% but it didnt help.

I need to make it working in such a way that the container width would be the device width and there should be exactly 1 slide shown in it at a time.

How do I fix this?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/9dJfQ/30/)

**EDIT:**

It seems this plugin needs the slide width explicitly mentioned. `width: auto` wouldnt work either. Does anybody have any suggestion?

Comment: there is a big problem in your question in fiddle i can see slider works on click but if you hide other slider how are you planning to make this slider work

Comment: @himanshu I need to make it work by swiping.

Comment: ok let me try what i can do